# pgRouting for postgresql 9.0?

Tags: pgrouting

Is pgRouting 1.05 compatible with postgresql9.0 Win32? I am a newbie, and I have spent three days trying to build it for postgresql9.0, but without success in the end.
Thanks.

---

Yes, you are right. I am using postgresql 9.0. Building all of those dependent libraries has obviously done something to my head. LOL. 
I had to build everything from scratch, since I don't do C/C++ development. I followed the instructions here for Win32 (http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/howto/build_on_windows.html: [Win32 build instruction](http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/howto/build_on_windows.html)), and with changes here and there because the instruction is quite old, and some of the libs I am using are newer.

After 3 days, I was able to progress to the final build of pgrouting, but got the following errors(see below). I am actually ready to go back to postgresql 8.4, but it just seems a lot of time wasted, and I had gone this far, and if someone can point out where things might have been wrong, maybe we can get a binary build to share. Thanks.

Here are some other libraries info: boost 1.47, cgal 3.8, gaul 0.1849, cmake 2.8, MinGW/msys 5.?

```
    [  8%] Building C object extra/tsp/src/CMakeFiles/routing_tsp.dir/tsp.obj
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/postgres.h:47:0,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.h:25,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:22:
C:/postgresql/include/server/c.h:284:2: error: #error must have a working 64-bit integer datatype
In file included from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.h:25:0,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:22:
C:/postgresql/include/server/postgres.h:550:34: error: expected ')' before 'X'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/genam.h:21:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:17,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/storage/lock.h:400:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int64'
C:/postgresql/include/server/storage/lock.h:412:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int64'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:17:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/access/genam.h:147:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'index_getbitmap'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:21:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/xlog.h:19,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/heapam.h:20,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/pgtime.h:23:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'pg_time_t'
C:/postgresql/include/server/pgtime.h:43:51: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
C:/postgresql/include/server/pgtime.h:44:48: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
C:/postgresql/include/server/pgtime.h:45:49: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:23:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/xlog.h:19,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/heapam.h:20,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/int8.h:26:53: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'int64'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/xlog.h:19:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/heapam.h:20,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:48:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Timestamp'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:49:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'TimestampTz'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:50:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'TimeOffset'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:62:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'TimeOffset'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:195:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PgStartTime'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:198:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PgReloadTime'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:315:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'GetCurrentTimestamp'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:317:45: error: expected ')' before 'start_time'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:319:52: error: expected ')' before 'start_time'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:323:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'time_t_to_timestamptz'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:324:18: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'timestamptz_to_time_t'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:326:51: error: expected ')' before 't'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:328:67: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'Timestamp'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:329:35: error: expected ')' before 'dt'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:331:31: error: expected ')' before 'dt'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:336:18: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SetEpochTimestamp'
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/timestamp.h:339:45: error: expected ')' before 'dt1'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/access/heapam.h:20:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/access/xlog.h:249:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'TimestampTz'
C:/postgresql/include/server/access/xlog.h:285:44: error: expected ')' before '*' token
C:/postgresql/include/server/access/xlog.h:288:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'GetSystemIdentifier'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/execdesc.h:18:0,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:49,
                 from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:1537:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int64'
C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:1616:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int64'
C:/postgresql/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:1758:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int64'
In file included from C:/postgresql/include/server/executor/spi.h:17:0,
                 from d:/pgroute/pgrouting-1.05/extra/tsp/src/tsp.c:25:
C:/postgresql/include/server/utils/portal.h:169:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'TimestampTz'
make[2]: *** [extra/tsp/src/CMakeFiles/routing_tsp.dir/tsp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [extra/tsp/src/CMakeFiles/routing_tsp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I hope you mean Postgres 9. Do you need to use 9.0?

Comment: Cool! Postgres 6.0 was released in '97, these are the release notes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/release-6-0.html
Do I get points for this? ;-)

Comment: http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html : you need postgresql>=8.0. If you are running a more recent postgresql version you should provide info on what you tried and where you got errors to get any sensible answer

Comment: dll for postgres 9 you did?
Please pass me the binary

Comment: I have win XP, Postgre 8.4 and pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2. Where I can find pgRouting for Postgre 9.0? p.s. I can't add comment, so I wrote this as answer ...

Answer (score 2):

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2010-10/msg00605.php refers to the same problems.

But I would actually recommend you *not* to build from source if you have little experience. If security updates come out you will have to compile everything again, if you have problems it is harder for others to reproduce the problem if you are not using a binary build. Binaries for pgrouting and postgis exist: http://www.wiesenhaan.com/pgrouting/pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2.zip
http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows