# How to compile pgRouting 1.05 binaries for Windows?

Tags: pgrouting

Anybody with a compiled 1.05 binary for (Windows / PostgreSQL 8.4 / PostGIS 1.5.3) or a detailed description on how to compile?

Comment: Somebody tried it. Still waiting for answers. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14674/pgrouting-for-postgresql-9-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/sanak/pgrouting/blob/master/BUILD.msvc90) (**dead link**) is a detailed instruction how to build pgRouting for Windows. And [here](https://github.com/sanak/pgrouting/downloads) is already compiled pgRouting for Windows PostgreSQL 9.1(x86) with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: That's really useful. I emailed `pgrouting` to ask them to put a link on their site - at the moment the last windows build is early 2010.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry I had moved abobe link to https://github.com/sanak/pgrouting4w/tree/windows-binary .

And I recommend MinGW build module(pgRouting-git-sanak-mingw_20120310_pg-9.1(x86).zip),
because of shooting star long route issue. (see [PGRouting with 1.05 library in Postgres 9.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20793/pgrouting-with-1-05-library-in-postgres-9-1))

MinGW branch and build instruction is as follows.
https://github.com/sanak/pgrouting4w/tree/mingw
 +- BUILD.mingw