# Is Shooting Star broken in PGRouting 1.05?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I'm using pgrouting DLL 1.05 with postgresql 9.1.
All required function installed.

Astar and Dijkstra work fine with sample data but "SHOOTING STAR" is not considering "reverse_cost".

Also if i try long route then it gives server disconnected error.

```
"Do you want to attempt to reconnect to the database?"
```

And then I need to restart the postgresql service.

Answer (score 3):

Did you use Windows Microsoft Visual Stdio 2008 build module?

If so, I confirmed the same issue, and uploaded the fixed binary (download from [here](https://github.com/sanak/pgrouting4w/tree/windows-binary) (2012/02/26)), so please check this new one.

Regards,

Comment: Thank a lot. Its working. Need to do more testing. Thanks again.

Comment: It works for short segment. If i give the long roaute its not working. Also "REVERSE_CSOT" is not considered in the route. same problem which is in 1.03. Please help.

Comment: Thanks for quick validation.I confirmed that long route shooting star query failed on Windows, although the same query succeeded on Ubuntu 11.04 with PostgreSQL 9.1.
It may take a long time to fix this Windows msvc specific issue.

Comment: Could be interesting have this comments also in pgrouting-users@lists.osgeo.org mail list...
please use it...
thanks

Comment: Still the pgrouting 1.05 not working properly. Reverse_cost not considered.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, > Hi jfuentes, I will sent those (but mingw) modules to official site during June, and use the mainling-list that time. > Hi Amol, see http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/pgrouting-dev/2012-June/thread.html - "shortest_path_shooring_star" thread.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using undirected graphs? Those ignore the  `“has_reverse_cost”` setting [according to the docs](http://pgrouting.org/docs/foss4g2008/ch09.html).