# Shooting star algorithm in postgres 8.4 and postgis1.4 showing fatal error and remaining are working fine

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

When I try to run this shooting star algorithm, the postgis suddenly loosing connection to postgres and showing error no connection to server

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path_shooting_star('
   SELECT gid AS id, 
      start_id::int4 AS source, 
      end_id::int4 AS target, 
      shape_leng::float8 AS cost,
      x1, y1, x2, y2,
      rule, to_cost
   FROM viz_network',
   173,
   97,
   false,
   false);
```

And digkstra algorithm is working fine :

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
  SELECT gid AS id, 
      start_id::int4 AS source, 
      end_id::int4 AS target, 
      shape_leng::float8 AS cost
  FROM viz_network',
  1,
  310,
  false,
  false);
```

Comment: Shooting star is pgrouting function so you should add the version of pgrouting. Also, please see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20793/is-shooting-star-broken-in-pgrouting-1-05

Comment: @JakubKania The link for new binaries is broken.

Comment: Well, you'd have to ask @sanak about it then. But he wrote he will update the official builds and you still haven't wrote what version of pgrouting you're using, is it the latest one?